# data.Succeeded == true seems to be not working properly in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular5

I try to create registration in Angular 5. Everything seems to be working properly (accounts are added to the database) however I always get error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.Errors[0]')` Any ideas what is wrong? It seems to me that there is a problem with `data.Succeeded` it looks like `Succeeded` was undefined and condition always achieves `else`.

```
  OnSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.userService.registerUser(form.value)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        if (data.Succeeded == true) {
          this.resetForm(form);
          this.toastr.success('User registration successful');
        }
        else
          this.toastr.error(data.Errors[0]);
      });
  }
```

Comment: try to print `data` see what is the details

Comment: `data.Errors` seems to be `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code assumes that userService.registerUser returns a data structure with the property "Succeeded" set to true. If that's not the case, the else statement gets executed and the first error ([0]) in the data.Errors gets passed to the toaster. If data.Errors is null, you get the "undefined is not an object."

```
OnSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.userService.registerUser(form.value)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
         if (data.key !== '') {
           this.resetForm(form);
           this.toastr.success('User registration successful');
         }
         else
           this.toastr.error('Registration failed');
      });
  }
```

Comment: But how can I check why `Succeeded` is not equals `true`?

Comment: It returns token `{key: "ced8486130fec087f81c58c15680242380ea1"}` Any ideas how can I check whether user registration was ended correctly? Because in the example that I took from tutorial (`data.Succeeded == true`) it seems to be not working properly.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

```
OnSubmit(form: NgForm) {
this.userService.registerUser(form.value).subscribe(
      data => {
      this.getUsers();
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.toastr.success('Project Information is posted successfully');
        return true;

      },
  error => {
     console.error('Error posting Project Information!');
     return Observable.throw(error);
   }

   );


 }
```